# Is there any facebook graph api to get updated posts in a page by an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to use graph API to get posts get updated between two given timestamps? I don't want to use FQL, as it is deprecated. And I want to know we can get updates using graph API itself instead of using Subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `since` and `until` tags along with your query for the posts?
That's what the API seems to recommend under Time Based Pagination : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api